# Would killing Jerona block access to the Emerald Grove?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

There is an NPC named Jerona who opens the gate to Emerald Grove whenever I get near the entrance. If Jerona was killed, either by an enemy or by myself, would that block off access to the Emerald Grove? Or would there be some alternate way to enter?

[image: Jerona by the gate]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways into Emerald Grove, so should there be no one available to open the gate, you can:

- Open it yourself as seen in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yUsdbCAsRO8).  Simply use Misty Step to get up the gates controls.
- Use the [Underground Passage](https://baldursgate3.wiki.fextralife.com/Underground+Passage).  Mind your step though, there are some traps. The entrance can be found [here](https://mapgenie.io/baldurs-gate-3/maps/wilderness?locationIds=53995).  You *may* need enough Strength though to make the jump up into Emerald Grove once you reach the end of the passage.  Here is a screenshot of the exit through the passage that lands you in Emerald Grove:

[image: underground passage entrance in emerald grove]

Comment: Will the gate no longer open automatically if Jerona is dead?

Comment: @Stevoisiak I assume so, if no other NPC takes over for her. I believe there is a spell you can also learn on certain classes to summon a magical hand to perform environmental actions, so I bet that would work too

Comment: @Stevoisiak I think I also saw videos of people blowing up the gate using explosive barrels.  So, there is likely many ways to still get into the grove.